# Elasticsearch for a large searchable database

Tags: elasticsearch

I am currently looking for a database storage system which can hold my data, and make it easily searchable via PHP.

I have about 65 million text files which range from a few bytes up to 10 megabytes each. Total current size is about 1,5TB of raw data.

I want to be able to quickly search these files, and someone pointed out that Elasticsearch could be a good candidate.

Ideally I would run this on one powerful machine with a lot of RAM, and plenty of disk storage.

I know Elasticsearch uses Java. Would using/searching such a large amount of data be efficient and fast with Elasticsearch?

Is there maybe a better storage system that I could use instead of Elasticsearch?

Answer (score 0):

ES is build for searching large databases so, yes, it would likely be a good candidate.

> Ideally I would run this on one powerful machine with a lot of RAM, and plenty of disk storage.

ES is build as a distributed database, meaning that in a production environment it runs best on 3 or more nodes (node = server).  The more nodes you have, the faster you can insert and the faster you can search the data.  That is the "magic" of ES and other distributed databases.

So my recommendation: try it out on development but plan on a ***minimum*** of 2 nodes in production, perhaps more.